# Save page with css, js and images using watir

Tags: ruby, parsing, web-scraping, watir, watir-webdriver

How can I save page with all its content using watir-webdriver?
`browser.html` save only browser's elements. If I open file where I dumped `browser.html` there is no styling.

Also `browser.html` doesn't save iframes. I can loop through iframes and save them separately, but they will be separated from the main page.

I record only htmls for now, maybe later I'll save screenshots, because there is no simple way to dump whole page with its css and images.

```
require 'fileutils'
class Recorder

  attr_reader :request, :counter, :browser

  # request should contain w(login_id start_time)
  def initialize(request)
    @request, @counter = request, 1
    # Settings class contains my configs (enable recording, paths, etc.)
    FileUtils.mkpath(path) if Settings.recorder.record and !File.exists?(path)
  end

  def record(hash)
    return unless Settings.recorder.record
    @browser = hash["browser"]
    record_html(hash)
    record_frames(hash)
    @counter += 1
  end

private

  # hash should contain (method_name browser)
  def record_html(hash)
    File.open("#{path}#{generate_file_name(hash)}", "w") do |file|
      file.write("<!--#{browser.url}-->\n")
      file.write(browser.html)
    end
  end

  def record_frames(hash)
    browser.frames.each_with_index do |frame, index|
      File.open("#{path}#{generate_file_name(hash, index + 1)}", "w") do |file|
        file.write("<!--#{browser.url}-->\n")
        file.write(frame.html)
      end
    end
  end

  def path
    "#{Settings.recorder.path}/#{request["login_id"]}/#{request["start_time"]}/"
  end

  def generate_file_name(hash, frame=nil)
    return "#{counter}-#{hash["method_name"]}.html" if frame.nil?
    "#{counter}-frame#{frame}-#{hash["method_name"]}.html"
  end
end
```

Comment: What have you tried? We'd like to see some source code you've written to know you're on the right track.

Comment: This sort of thing seems like it might be better suited to nokogiri instead of watir-webdriver, since nokogiri is all about parsing HTML. What's your use case?

Comment: Nokogiri is not an option, because it has no idea about session. Pages, which I want to save, appear only after loggin in to a web service.

Comment: Ивааааан) No updates so far ?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about Watir but for those who might want to save a page (including CSS and JavaScript that are directly in the page) using Selenium WebDriver (which Watir wraps around), the easiest way is to use [the page_source method (of the WebDriver class)](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Driver.html#page_source-instance_method). As its name suggests, it gives so whole source. Then it's just a matter of saving to a new file, like so :

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:firefox)
driver.get(URL_of_page_to_save)
file = File.new(filename, "w")
file.puts(driver.page_source)
file.close
```

It won't save the JavaScript or CSS inside other files though.

Comment: Does not work, just tried to save current page, look what I've got https://www.dropbox.com/s/jfgyb943hu8rjvn/selenium_page_src.html

Comment: I don't think that anything like that is really possible, using cdn already does not allow to download styles in a simple way